# Changing paragraph spacing in a specific part

Tags: paragraphs, exercises

I am working with the `exercise` and in some of my questions (when I have large equations), I would like to have a different paragraph spacing. Is there a way to do this?
This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, exercise, multicol}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 

\begin{document}

\parskip=12pt

\begin{Exercise}[label=Ex1]
\Question {Here the spacing is normal}
    \subQuestion {$ x^2 + x $}
    \subQuestion {$ 2x + a $}

\Question {Here I want more space between paragraphs}
\parskip=24pt # This has no effect
    \Question {$ \dfrac{x^2 - 2}{x^2 + x + 1} $}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{2x^2 + 2x + 1}{x^2 + x + 2} $

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
\vspace{2in}
```

create blank space for answers.